# Spring boot REST code to send email using javax works when I build as jar but not when I build as war

Tags: spring-boot, jakarta-mail

I have a Spring boot REST API which sends email using javax mail. I tested it by creating jar and running as spring boot app (embedded server). However, when I deploy the same code on tomcat (by creating a war), the code does not send email successfully and hangs at the below line:

```
Transport.send(message);
```

The code runs till this stage but hangs here, instead of sending the email. What can be the issue and how can I resolve it?
thanks

Comment: What does the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) show?

Comment: I added the below code to run on the debug but still did not see any error message   `boolean debug=true;
  session.setDebug(debug); `.   This works fine when I do not use tomcat but when I deploy on tomcat and run it just hangs at this stage `Transport.send(message); `